# changing permalink for custom template in posts of a certain category

Tags: permalinks, single

I've created a unique single post template to give people the option of reading all posts of a certain category using the awesome "reveal.js" which they access via this link

```
<a href="?show=presentation/">presentation</a>
```

The problem is the ugly URLs, which end up looking like

```
website.com/post-name/?show=presentation
website.com/completely-different-post-name/?show=presentation
```

I would like them to look like

```
website.com/post-name/presentation/
website.com/completely-different-post-name/presentation/
```

I've spent the last 10 or so hours trying to figure this out (I haven't even gone to sleep yet, lol); unfortunately, nothing has worked.

Is there a way to do this?

As a side note, the site I'm trying to do this on is installed in a subdirectory (localhost/wp) but I'm developing this for my actual website which is installed in a top level directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this via the [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)'s [`add_rewrite_endpoint`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint):

```
function wpa89344_add_presentation_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'presentation', EP_PERMALINK );
}
add_action('init', 'wpa89344_add_presentation_endpoint');
```

Then in your template or wherever you differentiate a presentation vs normal view, check the global `$wp_query` for the presence of the `presentation` query var:

```
global $wp_query;
if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['presentation'] ) ){
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single_wide_report.php");
} else {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single_normal_report.php");
}
```

Note that you need to visit the permalinks settings page after adding the endpoint to flush permalinks and create the new rewrite rules.

EDIT- Output of `$wp_query` in `single.php`:

[image]

Comment: thanks Milo! Looks like I had the first part right (at one point); could you explain the second part just a bit more for me. At the moment I'm calling both templates with   
`switch ($_GET["show"]) {
    case "presentation":
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single_wide_report.php");
        break;
    default:
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single_normal_report.php");
        break;
}`

Comment: see edit above.

Comment: is there supposed to be a semi-colon after `global $wp_query`? Without one, my posts go blank on me. With a semi-colon, though, I can't access the presentations template at all (even with the old `?show=presentation`) Probably I'm missing something.

Comment: yeah, sorry, missing the semicolon. [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) to see php errors. have you flushed permalinks? view the `$wp_query` global to see if the query var is being set: `print_r($wp_query);`.

Comment: no worries, I'm learning lots. Everything's clear with the debug, there weren't any errors. And I'm flushing permalinks. Lastly, I added `print_r($wp_query);` to `single_normal_report.php` I'm not too sure what to look for though. Didn't see any reference to the templates

Comment: you're looking at the query vars to see if `presentation` is set or not. where are you adding the code to load your template? in `single.php`. have a look at the [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter.

Comment: also note that action hooks / functions like the first part should be in your theme's `functions.php` file or a plugin, not a template file.

Comment: I got the function in `functions.php` yep. The other part is in `single.php`. I placed `print_r($wp_query);` in `single.php` as well; sadly, there was no mention of `presentation`.

Comment: NB The basic template, ie. `single_normal_report.php` is being called ok; but when I click on the presentation link (or add `/presentation/` to the end of the url), I get redirected to another post that starts with the word `presentation`

Comment: the endpoint isn't being added for whatever reason. I suggest disabling plugins and switching to a default theme, then adding the code there and testing results. see edit above for results when added to the default twenty twelve theme.

Comment: ok, looks like it's my template (it works flawlessly in twenty twelve) I guess I'll just have to dig in! Thanks for all the help Milo, I really appreciate it.

Comment: how about that, I just figured it out!!! The problem seems to have been where I placed the function in `functions.php` - I was putting it beneath my code for a couple taxonomies I got going. When I placed the function above that code, it worked! Thanks again Milo